# ssh -w: Bad tun device 'tun0'

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ip, ssh-tunneling

I'm attempting to create an SSH tunnel and utilize it as a standard network interface.

Here is what I have tried:

`myuser@client-pc`:

```
ip tuntap add mode tun user myuser name tun0
ip address add dev tun0 192.168.20.1/24
ip link set tun0 up
```

`root@server-pc`:

```
ip tuntap add mode tun user root name tun0
ip address add dev tun0 192.168.20.2/24
ip link set tun0 up
```

When attempting to use `ssh -w tun0 root@server-pc`, I encountered an issue:

```
Bad tun device 'tun0'
```

Running it with `-vvv` yielded identical results.

What could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: Isn't `ssh` supposed to create the tunnel device specified via `-w`?

Comment: @muru I thought that ‘ssh’ just attaches to the tun device, not creating it. Anyway I tried to use nonexistent name and run ‘ssh’ under ‘root’, but it didn’t work due to the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to specify only the number without the `tun` prefix.

This information can be found in the man page for SSH, `man ssh`:

```
-w local_tun[:remote_tun]
     Requests tunnel device forwarding with the specified tun(4) devices between the
     client (local_tun) and the server (remote_tun).

     The devices may be specified by numerical ID or the keyword “any”, which uses the
     next available tunnel device.  If remote_tun is not specified, it defaults to “any”.
     See also the Tunnel and TunnelDevice directives in ssh_config(5).
```

"**Numerical ID**" or "**any**" are the only valid values.

So the command should be:

```
ssh -w 0 root@server-pc
```